# How to clean up photos that are in multiple Google Photos albums?

Tags: google-photos

I've ended up with some photos in more than one album.
(E.g. `2018 Miscellaneous` and `2018 Vacation`)

Is there an easy way to remove all the photos from Miscellaneous that are also in Vacation?

And more generally is there a way to find all photos that are in more than one album?